# how to populate sqlite values into spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

I can not retrieve data from the database into the spinner. This is the source code that can not bring the spinner. I've been making methods and retrieve it from the database but the data from the database does not show up as well. please help ..

```
private void loadModuledate(){
    DBDataSource db = new DBDataSource(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<ProductModule> lables = db.getAllmodule();
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<ProductModule> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ProductModule>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    edModul.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

here is my DBDatasource.java

```
public ArrayList<ProductModule> getAllmodule() {
    ArrayList<ProductModule> daftarproductmodule = new ArrayList<ProductModule>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.PRODUCT_MODULE,
            allProductModule, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ProductModule ProductModule = cursorToProductModule(cursor);
        daftarproductmodule.add(ProductModule);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return daftarproductmodule;
}
```

here is my log cat

```
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ims.app.mobileorder/ims.app.mobileorder.FormComplain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at ims.app.mobileorder.DBDataSource.getAllmodule(DBDataSource.java:101)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at ims.app.mobileorder.FormComplain.loadModuledate(FormComplain.java:63)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at ims.app.mobileorder.FormComplain.onCreate(FormComplain.java:46)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
02-24 14:57:07.445: E/AndroidRuntime(16981):    ... 11 more
02-24 14:57:10.698: E/Trace(17357): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Just check whether your sqlite database object is null or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<ProductModule> getAllmodule() {
```

> ***SQLiteDataBase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.openDataBase();***

```
        ArrayList<ProductModule> daftarproductmodule = new ArrayList<ProductModule>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.PRODUCT_MODULE,
                allProductModule, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            ProductModule ProductModule = cursorToProductModule(cursor);
          daftarproductmodule.add(ProductModule);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return daftarproductmodule;
      }
```

i hope you will solved your error.